# Access (x)color definitions from lua

Tags: color, luatex

The package `xcolor` has a way of extracting the components of a colour specification:

```tex
\extractcolorspec{red!50}\spec
% \spec now has the value {rgb}{1,0.5,0.5}
```

Is there a way of doing the same, but from lua code instead of tex?

Comment: well you naturally can reimplement all the calculations in lua if you want.

Comment: That is what I was trying to avoid :)

Comment: Won't this question be more appropriate for Stackoverflow since it is lua-based?

Comment: There is a `luacolor` package, which has `*.sty` and `*.lua` components. It is used (for example) by package `luatypo`. Although it may not directly address the OP's situation, surely this is not a purely Lua question. I do not know enough coding to determine whether or not the existing `luacolor` has what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following workaround, but would welcome a more idiomatic approach.

On the TeX side, we need a few allocations (those could be done in pure lua, if needed):

```tex
\makeatletter

\newtoks \getcolor@runtoks
\newtoks \getcolor@spectoks
\newtoks \getcolor@valtoks

\getcolor@runtoks{%
    \expandafter\extractcolorspec
        \expandafter{\the\getcolor@spectoks}\getcolor@spec
    \expandafter\getcolor@valtoks
        \expandafter\@gobble\getcolor@spec}

\makeatother
```

And then the following lua definition will do:

```lua
function getcolor(spec)
    tex.scantoks('getcolor@spectoks', 0, spec)
    tex.runtoks 'getcolor@runtoks'
    return tex.toks['getcolor@valtoks']
end
```

This return value is a comma-separated string that will likely need further processing. However, this saves the trouble of re-implementing all calculations in lua.